# Add dynamic content to a template in code igniter

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter

I am trying a HTML/CSS file to convert to a template. I asked for help but I didn't receive any suggestions in that post yet I tried to figure out a way to create a template. I am having few glitches in doing that. My controller has main.php file which is the main page of the website, and I have register where the header, footer, and rest remain same except that main content changes when the page loads.

I have the following template in the views folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
   <title><?= $title ?></title>

   <style type="text/css"  >
       @import url('<?=base_url()?>/includes/front.css');
       @import url('<?=base_url()?>/images/');
   </style>

</head>
<body>
   <div id="container">
       <div id="header">
            <?= $logo ?> <!--This is an image tag to display the image on the template -->
            <?= $topnav ?>
       </div>

       <div id="menubar">
            <?= $menulist ?>
       </div>

       <div id="maincontent">
           <?= $flashcontent ?>
           <?= $resources ?>
           <?= $registerForm ?>
       </div>

       <div id="footer">
           <div>
               <?= $footertable1 ?>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the

> div id = maincontent

This is the div tag which would be changing when a site loads. In my template I have included <

```
<?= $flashcontent ?> <?= $resource ?> and  <?= registerForm ?>
```

The flashcontent and resources are supposed to be in the main page and registerForm is supposed to be shown when I click on register in the main page. I have been reading the template user guide in the code igniter but I am unable to understand how to make this dynamic. Please help me in getting over this issue.

This is the template.php in config folder.

```
$template['active_group'] = 'default';
$template['default']['template'] = 'template.php';
$template['default']['regions'] = array(
   'title',
   'logo' => array(
        'content' => array(''),
        'name' => 'Logo',
        'wrapper' => '<img>',
        'attributes' => array('id' => 'logo')
    ),
    'topnav' => array(
        'content' => array(),
        'name' => 'Topnav',
        'wrapper' => '<div>',
        'attributes' => array('id' => 'topnav', 'class' => 'topnav')
    ),
    'menulist' => array(
        'content' => array('<li>
                            <a href="#"> Home </a>
                            <a href="#"> Generator </a>
                            <a href="#"> News </a>
                            <a href="#"> Forum </a>
                            <a href="#"> About </a>
                            <a href="#"> Feedback </a>
                            </li>'),
        'name' => 'Menulist',
        'wrapper' => '<ul>',
        'attributes' => array('class' => 'menulist')
    ),
   'flashcontent' => array(
       'content' => array(''),
       'name' => 'Flashcontent',
       'wrapper' => '<div>',
       'attributes' => array('id' => 'flashcontent')
   ),
    'resources' => array(
       'content' => array(''),
       'name' => 'Resources',
       'wrapper' => '<div>',
       'attributes' => array('id' => 'resources')
   ),
    'registerForm' => array(
      'content' => array(),
        'name' => 'Registerform',
        'wrapper' => '<div>',
        'attributes' => array('id' => 'registerForm')
    ),
   'footertable1' => array(
       'content' => array('<ul> 
                            <li> <a href="../main">Home</a>
                            <a href="#">News & Events</a>
                            <a href="#">Forum</a>
                            <a href="#">About us</a>
                            <a href="#">Contact us</a>
                            <a href="#">Terms of use</a>
                            <a href="#">Privacy policy</a>
                            <a href="#">Site map</a>
                            </li>
                           </ul>'),
       'name' => '',
       'wrapper' => '<div>',
       'attributes' => array('id' => 'footertable1')
   )
);
$template['default']['parser'] = 'parser';
$template['default']['parser_method'] = 'parse';
$template['default']['parse_template'] = FALSE;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're working with [Colin Williams Template library](http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/reference.html#writing).

I haven't looked at it too much but take a read @ http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/reference.html#manipulation

> ```
> $this->template->add_region($name, $settings = array())
> ```
>
> The add_region() method allows one to dynamically add regions for
>   writing. At a minimum, a $name must be
>   supplied to identify the region.
>   Optionally, a $settings array can be
>   passed in to provide default content,
>   wrappers and attributes.

```
$this->template->add_region('flash');
$this->template->write_view('flash', 'some_flash');    
$this->template->add_region('login');
$this->template->write_view('login', 'some_login');
```

### Edit

(Again, assuming you are using the template library I think you are),

You have a region `content` in your template. You have a view called `registerForm` which contains just the form.

In your `controller method` for register, you simply have to do:

`$this->template->write_view('content', 'registerForm');`

The library will load the content of the view `registerForm` in to the `content` region.

You can have as many regions as you like, obviously, but the template library allows you to define an area (a region) that you want any content to appear, and then outputs your HTML or views directly in to the region.

Either I misunderstand but I don't think I can explain it much simpler than this. The docs are rather good as well.

## Edit the second

Here's a sample method from a project I did a while back using this library.

```
class Welcome extends Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->template->set_template('my_template'); 
        // as defined in config/template.php    
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->template->write('title', 'This is my $title region');

            // here I am writing some views to my regions $content and $sidebar
        // content/home-page-view is just a view containing text.

        $this->template->write_view('content', 'content/home-page-view');
        $this->template->write_view('sidebar', 'sidebar/home-page-sidebar');

        // lets go..
        $this->template->render();
    }
```

now when I access `mysite.com/welcome/index` my HTML template will be displayed with the content I wrote in the method.

My HTML template looks a little like:

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $content; ?>

<?php echo $sidebar; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

My config/template.php file looks like this:

```
$template['default']['template'] = 'template/master';
$template['default']['regions'] = array(
    'title',
    'content',
    'sidebar'
    );
$template['default']['parser'] = 'parser';
$template['default']['parser_method'] = 'parse';
$template['default']['parse_template'] = FALSE;
```

`template/master` refers to a file in my views folder (template/master.php) which contains my layout (as above).

Comment: The question which concerns me is that should I echo $maincontent in the template.php. Should I have to remove that or should I leave it like that. When I am using the same template for the register, I dont need the flashcontent and resources in my template. I just need registerForm to be echoed out. With this add_region, set_template I am not sure how does the computer know that I have to place my registerForm exactly inside the maincontainer div tag

Comment: Also you tell CI which region to write to, so it knows to place `registerForm` where `$mainContent` is, for instance.

Comment: Thanks. I understand what you explained. The main concern I have is that when I load the register view which is supposed to only show the registerForm. It also shows the flashcontent and resources above the registerForm view. This is where I am confused. Is there a method to destroy the flashcontent and resources.

Comment: The user guide states it's not recommended to include markup inside your template config. Just define regions, and if you need content, write to them. Otherwise you will have content there regardless. I don't think you can dynamically remove them

Answer (score 3):

Are you using a CMS or a custom database? Where are the dynamic elements coming from?

The basics for making a dynamic element are as follows:

Above your html:

```
<?php
$logosrc="mylogo.gif";
?>
```

Then in your html:

```
<img src='<? echo $logosrc;?>' />
```

Comment: I am using a custom database. In controllers folder I have main.php, and register.php, I am loading the flashcontent and resource. I have to load the registration form in regiter.php instead of flash content, however I have all three flash content, resources and form. The logo image is from the CSS i.e., I have used background image in the CSS, which it is failing to retrieve

Comment: @Ross you are right. The path for the images folder was broken. And now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `uri_segment` to control your dynamic content.
   In your `main.php`:

   ```
   <?php
   //...
   $template['registerForm'] = '';
   if($this->uri->segment(1) === false) {
       $template['registerForm'] = $this->load->view('form/registration');
   }
   //...
   ?>
   ```
2. Use JavaScript to load new page when clicked. Make a simple function in `main.php` just to load that form template and show that form via ajax.

Comment: Can you explain me a little more in detail. I am new to codeigniter. I would be happy if you can provide me with a link which can give me an in depth approach to solve this problem